# How to load data while scrolling horizontally and on a DIV overflow?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I’m working on this horizontal scrollbar that grabs content from the database when you scroll to the farthest right. Here's an example of what we want to do:
[http://designarchives.aiga.org/#/entries/%2Bcollections%3A%2250%20Books%2F50%20Covers%20of%202009%22/_/grid/relevance/asc/0/48/120](http://designarchives.aiga.org/#/entries/+collections%3a%2250%20Books/50%20Covers%20of%202009%22/_/grid/relevance/asc/0/48/120)

I found useful tutorial here but its vertical scroll:
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

So far it is working vertically, but how do you load data while scrolling horizontally and on a DIV overflow, not the window?

Comment: @TerryR: Why don't you post the comment as an answer?

Comment: @FloydPink wasn't sure if posting existing responses qualified as an answer.  Thanks for suggesting it.  I removed the comments and reposted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is broken but I wrote an accepted answer on how to work with horizontal scrolling divs here. Hopefully that helps you.

Here's the working fiddle in case it wasn't obvious where to look. [jsfiddle.net/gAMyR/26](http://jsfiddle.net/gAMyR/26)

Comment: Thanks for the respond. The URL is http://designarchives.aiga.org/
Just click on the images under "Featured Collections" that will bring you the page where you see the horizontal scroll. I used your code but how do you dynamically load more stuff when you scroll to the end?

Comment: Using the [endless scrolling](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/) technique, you need to keep track of what elements were loaded and when you reach the last one add more.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what server side language you use.  The important part is the client side script, your ss code just returns the requested results which I assume you already have working if you have a gallery of some kind.  You can look at [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/) or just Google "endless scrolling PHP"